# automatically load ajax loaded content (jquery ui tabs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) to load some content via Ajax when the user clicks on the tabs. What I want is to load the content of the first tab automatically when the page loads without the user having to click on the tab. How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the tab load method for the first tab (0) on page load:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "load" , 0 );
}
```

This just loads the content.  If you want to select a tab, use `select`, which also loads the content.  This shouldn't be needed if you are loading the default tab:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , tabIndex );
}
```

**Edit:**  For newer versions of jQuery, you need to use the `active` option:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", tabIndex );
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/8zkfrbee

Comment: Have exact issue but this solution doesn't work. I am using `jquery 1.10.2` and `jquery-ui 1.11.1` Could you please help?

Comment: @MrudangVora For newer versions of jQuery, you need to use `.tabs("option", "active", tabIndex)`. Demo: jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/8zkfrbee

Comment: Tried but it doesn't automatically load `partialview` on first tab unless it is clicked. I am trying to load the `partialview` on each tab click using ajax.

Comment: @MrudangVora It's difficult to debug your code without seeing it.  You are best off starting a new question rather than piggy-backing off this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "load" , 0 );
});
```

If you want you can also keep the content pre-loaded inside the first div that has an `id="tabs-1"` but if you use pre-loaded approach then you don't need to use a url in your first `<a>` inside `<li>` instead use

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1">First tab</a><li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can include elements within the top tag element to populate the tabs if you don't want to use ajax. The ID of the element containing the text just needs to match the anchor tag for the tab.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Hello, Tab One.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Hello, Tab Two.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```